# Is there a feedback system to know why edits are rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Since I have a lower reputation **all my edits are peer reviewed**. Some changes I make are accepted but **some others are rejected** but do not indicate **why they are rejected** which leaves the editor clueless.

[I can illustrate this with the following example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/how-to-build-a-career-path-to-be-an-architect)

The question was,

How to build a career path to be an Architect?

Which I changed to,

How to build a career path to be a Software Architect?

The change Software Architect was clarified by the author in the comments specified in the question section and I applied the change to the question but yet my edit was rejected in the peer review.

Is there a **feedback system of why are certain edits rejected to help editors improve their editing skills?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the [suggestions tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40327/karthik-sreenivasan?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on your profile page. This lists all the suggested edits you've made.

If you click on the [suggested edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/4066) link you'll see your edit and how it was resolved.

In this case the reason was:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

Basically you only added one word to the title rather than looking at the whole post and correcting other errors. That, coupled with the fact is was an old question were the reasons I would have rejected the edit had I seen it.

Comment: Specifically, it would've bumped a long-dead post for a redundant edit ("software architect" is implied on a site for software development).

Comment: Thanks ChrisF. That definitely gives more clarity.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Thanks Mark. It is an other arrow to the quiver that is necessary. Thanks for making my arsenal powerful!